# Ruby on Rails - Load State and city when Country and State is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have `countries, states & cities` Databases with their models `Country, State & City`.

*Current association:*

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Currently Im using this jQuery to only show states based on selected country, but it still loads all the states in the select[options] which slows down page load.

```
- jQuery ->
  states = $('#q_state_id_eq').html()
  update_states = ->
    country = $('#q_country_id_eq :selected').text()
    options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label=#{country}]").html()

    if options
      $('#q_state_id_eq').html(options)
      # Add in a blank option at the top
      $('#q_state_id_eq').prepend("<option value=''></option>")
      # Ensure that the blank option is selected
      $('#q_state_id_eq option:first').attr("selected", "selected");
    else
      $('#q_state_id_eq').empty()

  $('#q_country_id_eq').change ->
    update_states()

  update_states()
```

In my form (*I am using Simple_form_for*), how can I add **collection_select/select** for `countries, states & cities` and **ONLY LOAD**, **states** when a *country* is selected and load **cities** when a *state* is selected?

*PS: Loaded states and cities needs to be based on which country and state is selected.*

Is there any gem for what I am looking for or a Ajax solution?
*(other solutions are also appreciated)*

Comment: That's called a [cascading dropdown](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=cascading+dropdowns+in+rails&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=vTHQVvDHH4mowASrraTgAQ).

Comment: @ Mohamad Tnx, does it still load states and cities in page load or only when country and state is selected?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. I link to a google search "cascading dropdowns in Rails", not a specific implementation. Have a look at some of the links and I'm sure you will find a few good ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in rails without using any gem.

```
f.collection_select(:state_id, State.all, :id, :name, {},{:data => {  :remote => true,
                :url => url_for(:controller => "states", 
                                :action => "display_cities")
            }
    }
)
```

In display_cities action, filter cities based on the state_id passed. Use display_cities.js.erb to populate the div element with new html generated.

Comment: Tnx, currently I don't have a controllers for countries, states and cities. Do need to make them first?

Comment: No not required. it's not something mandatory, you can continue with the controller you are using. But for better practices you can put similar actions together under once class name